# PGF Math Error: Could not parse input

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Trying to plot a BER vs SNR function using erf function. However I get an error saying " Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '' as a floating point number, 
sorry. The unreadable part was near ''. (in '0.5-0.5*erf(sqrt(10**(x/10)))') "

```
\documentclass[convert={density=400,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfplotsset{
label style={anchor=near ticklabel},
xlabel style={yshift=0.8em},
ylabel style={yshift=-2em},
tick label style={font=\bfseries\small },
label style={font=\bfseries\small},
legend style={font=\bfseries\small},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
declare function={erf(\x)=%
  (1+(e^(-(\x*\x))*(-265.057+abs(\x)*(-135.065+abs(\x)%
  *(-59.646+(-6.84727-0.777889*abs(\x))*abs(\x)))))%
  /(3.05259+abs(\x))^5)*(\x>0?1:-1);},
declare function={erf2(\x,\y)=erf(\x)+erf(\y);}
]
\begin{axis}[xdomain:0:30,
width=\textwidth,
enlargelimits=false,
grid=major,
]
\addplot {0.5-0.5*erf(sqrt(10**(x/10)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There were a few things to change in your code:

- use `10^` not `10**`
- use `exp(...)` not `e^(...)`
- use `domain=...` not `xdomain=...`

Here's a complete MWE - remember to start small, and build on it slowly :) When you get an error, study the messages, comment out pieces of code, and keep tweaking until you fix it.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{
label style={anchor=near ticklabel},
xlabel style={yshift=0.8em},
ylabel style={yshift=-2em},
tick label style={font=\bfseries\small },
label style={font=\bfseries\small},
legend style={font=\bfseries\small},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        /pgf/declare function={erf(\x)=%
            (1+(exp(-(\x*\x))*(-265.057+abs(\x)*(-135.065+abs(\x)%
            *(-59.646+(-6.84727-0.777889*abs(\x))*abs(\x)))))%
            /(3.05259+abs(\x))^5)*(\x>0?1:-1);},
    ]
    \begin{axis}[domain=0:30,
            width=\textwidth,
            enlargelimits=false,
            grid=major,
        ]
        \addplot {0.5-0.5*erf(sqrt(10^(x/10)))};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The description of `pgf/declare function` in the TikZ/PGF manual (page 949 in version 3.0.0) seems to contradict parts of your answer: The list of arguments is given in parentheses, and variables are used as `\x`, `\y`, etc.

Comment: Could you try to compare results with a: your MWE (unmodified) and b: your MWE (with `\x` in function body and argument list)? At least for me, the first alternative plots an increasing function, while the second alternative plots a decreasing function tending towards zero. I'm pretty sure the second alternative is correct.