# how to determine piecewise constant function representing binary data

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I like to define function which represent binary data, but i stuck in this rather simple task ... my NWME is:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{data}{2}{%
    \pgfmathifthenelse{(or(\x<#1, \x>#2))}{1}{0}%
                                }
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red,  thick] (0,0) --
    plot [domain= 0:80, samples=160, smooth]  (\x,data(20,40));
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example gives error: "giving up on this path. ..." It seems that I do not understand howto use pgfmath for drawing such a simple function.

Drawing of this data function by hand is simple, but latter i like add a noise to this function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here, I complete the excellent cmhuges's answer to show how to use the `declare function` key:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{declare function={
      data(\a,\b,\x)=or(\x<\a, \x>\b)?1:0;
    }}
  \draw [red,thick] (0,0) -- plot [domain= 0:80,samples=160,smooth]  (\x,{data(20,40,\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your `pgfmath` is ok, but you need to use

```
\draw [red,  thick] plot [domain= 0:80, samples=160, smooth]  (\x,{data(20,40)});
```

Note the `{}` in `(\x,{data(20,40)})`. Here's a complete MWE:

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{data}{2}{%
    \pgfmathifthenelse{(or(\x<#1, \x>#2))}{1}{0}%
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw [red,  thick] plot [domain= 0:80, samples=160, smooth]  (\x,{data(20,40)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, you might like to explore the [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) package (which is based on `tikz`) as it eases some of the notation.

Comment: Huh, how simple, if know how. this sketch i will add to block scheme of communication channel, so I like to stay with pure tikz. And one more question, I need function data different from picture to picture. Is possible to include it definition inside tikzpicture?

Comment: @Zarko yes; see, for example, [PGF Math Error: Could not parse input](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/183360)

Comment: thank you for the link. The similar solution also gives Poul in his answer. But now i thinking, how to combine pgfplots and pure tikz picture. Graph given in my MWE is actually inside callout node, which described signals in scheme. I will experiment in my first spare time.